# Does CodeIgniter 4 'DatabaseHandler' support SQLSRV to store sessions

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I know the CI4 'DatabaseHandler' driver support relational databases such as MySQL or PostgreSQL to store sessions. I was able to use SQLSRV in CI3 and was wondering is this still a possibility.

Comment: yes  CI 4.2.7: [MSSQL via the SQLSRV driver (version 2005 and above only)](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/intro/requirements.html) and also this: https://forum.codeigniter.com/post-384412.html

Answer (score 0):

**SQLSRV store sessions**

I looked a bit more into the issue, currently there is a CI4 bug report [Bug: can't use SQLSRV as Session DatabaseHandler](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/issues/5693):

> Exception 'now' is not a recognized built-in function name [SQLSRV].
>
> I'm running Codeigniter in the configuration parameters mentioned
> above and when I set the application settings to store the sessions in
> the database (public $sessionDriver =
> 'CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\DatabaseHandler';) and I created the
> table "ci_sessions" in the SQL Server database but when I refresh any
> page I come across with one exception: Informing that the now()
> function does not exist.

the same report also suggests a work around from @websignsistemas  `/Session/Handlers/DatabaseHandler.php` changing the line (around 177) replacing the CI `now()` method with php's `getdate()`.

```
if (! $this->db->table($this->table)->set('timestamp', 'getdate()', false)->insert($insertData)) {
    return $this->fail();
}
```

by @kenjis, the issue awaits implementation:

> It seems SQL Server has advisory locking mechanisms.
> https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/176424/does-microsoft-sql-server-offer-an-advisory-locks-feature-like-postgres

**SQLSRV database connection:**

the CI4 docs confirm MSSQL support (via SQLSRV driver) [Server Requirements](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/intro/requirements.html):

> Currently supported databases are:
>
> ...
> MSSQL via the SQLSRV driver (version 2005 and above only)
> ...

connection is similar to CI3.x as pointed out by @InsiteFX [How to connect SQLSRV using SQLSRV driver?](https://forum.codeigniter.com/showthread.php?tid=78609&pid=384418#pid384418):

> make sure that you have all of the Microsoft drivers installed.
> It should not matter if it is CI 3 or CI 4 the configuration should be
> the same.